# Protocol and init argument

Tags: swift, protocols, init

An ex-collegue left a game uncomplete and undocumented.

When reading his code I found:

```
protocol EnemyMovement {
    func forward(speedPercent: Int)
    func reverse(speedPercent: Int)
    func left(speedPercent: Int)
    func right(speedPercent: Int)
}

protocol Enemy {
    var name: String {get set}
    var enemyMovement: EnemyMovement {get set}

    init (name: String, enemyMovement: EnemyMovement)
}

class EnemyInstance: Enemy {
    var name = "No enemy Name"
    var enemyMovement: EnemyMovement

    required init (name: String, enemyMovement: EnemyMovement) {
        self.name = name
        self.enemyMovement = enemyMovement
//...
}
```

I could not found a concrete instance of `EnemyInstance`, but if it's quite clear how to pass the name string, I don't understand how is EnemyMovement supposed to be passed.

```
var enemy = EnemyInstance(name: "zombie", enemyMovement?...)
```

Any idea?

Comment: The parameter is supposed to be an instance of a struct or class conforming to `EnemyMovement`

Comment: You need to declare a concrete type conforming to the `EnemyMovement` protocol (though in its current form it doesn't look like it should be a protocol at all) and pass that concrete type in to the initializer.

Comment: Oh, sorry, being thousand of lines, l'm really tired and I thought the idea of my colleague was to pass in an init function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since parameter has to be of type conforming to `EnemyMovement`, including these methods, you have to pass this object. So, you can try to create example struct

```
struct Movements: EnemyMovement {

    func forward(speedPercent: Int) {
        print(speedPercent)
    }

    func reverse(speedPercent: Int) {
        print(speedPercent)
    }

    func left(speedPercent: Int) {
        print(speedPercent)
    }

    func right(speedPercent: Int) {
        print(speedPercent)
    }

}
```

now as parameter for `EnemyInstance` initializer pass new instance of `Movements`

```
var enemy = EnemyInstance(name: "zombie", enemyMovement: Movements())
```

then you can call some method on `enemyMovement` property of your class and code inside this certain method gets executed (in this case it should print `speedPercent`)

```
required init (name: String, enemyMovement: EnemyMovement) {
    self.name = name
    self.enemyMovement = enemyMovement
    enemyMovement.forward(speedPercent: 2) // prints 2
}
```